# Getting first letter of every word in a sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read a text file and find out if the first letter every word in a sentence of the .txt file is vowel or not. I have this so far :

```
def main():
#Open, read and close the datafile
datafile=open(input('Enter File Name: '))
contents=datafile.read()
datafile.close

def startsWithVowel():
    if contents[0] in ['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u']:
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

This checks the first letter of the content of the data file but I need to check every word in the sentence but I am not sure how to work on first letter of each word in a sentence. Please Help!

Comment: you want to return True when? when all words of all lines start with a vowel? doesn't seem that useful to me.

Comment: Find out who to split a string in phyton. Split the string by spaces. Run a loop on each word to check if it starts with a vowel

Comment: Splitting the content up into words may be difficult if you want to ignore punctuation, digits, and other characters. A naive way to do it would be `contents.split()`.

Comment: @martineau thank you. exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main` function replace `contents=datafile.read()` with`contents = datafile.readlines()` and then correspondingly change your `startsWithVowel` as :

```
def startsWithVowel():
    for i in contents:
        if i[0] in ['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u']:
            return True
    return False
```

Also close your file as `datafile.close()` and use `True` and `False` instead of `true` and `false` for python .

Answer (score 4):

```
VOWELS = set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])


def starts_with_vowel(word):
    # make code more clean and efficient
    return word[0].lower() in VOWELS


# open the file using context manager - no need to do implicit open/close
with open(input('Enter File Name: ')) as f:
    for line in f:  # for every line in the file f
        for word in line.split(" "):  # split the line into word
            print(starts_with_vowel(word))
```

Comment: code-only answers are rarely useful. You have the occasion to write a good answer, don't waste it.

Comment: Thank you very much. So for this code, do I use readlines or just read?

Comment: This code work, as for line in f -> for every line in file f. also this open and close the file for you.